# Redis TYPE command of a hash return "none"

Tags: redis

So I create a hash like the following.

```
> HSET test k "v" k1 "v1"
> HGETALL test
1) "k"
2) "v"
3) "k1"
4) "v1"
```

Now I expect the type of the value in the key `test` to be "hash", as according to the docs. https://redis.io/commands/type/

However what I receive is "none". Why is this?

```
> type test
none
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my redis version is 2.8.24

use `HMSET` to set multi values.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HMSET test k "v" k1 "v1"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> HGETALL test
1) "k"
2) "v"
3) "k1"
4) "v1"
127.0.0.1:6379> type test
hash
```

my result is hash. maybe `test` was deleted after `hset`?

```
127.0.0.1:6379> del test
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> type test
none
```

Comment: Yes you were right. I was running a service which modifies redis in the background. smh.